# Adjust Sprite's Brightness

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, action, sprite, brightness

I have a button which when touched, I would like it to shrink and darken slightly. It's easy enough to shrink the button (`SKAction.scaleTo`), *but I can't seem to find a way of darkening it* (I'm not actually sure if it is possible to darken a sprite with an `SKAction`).

I can add a solid black sprite over the top of the button and adjust the alpha to darken when touched, but before I implement this into my code, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't something simpler available that I just haven't discovered yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SKAction.colorizeWithColor` or `SKAction.colorizeWithBlendFactor` may help you

Comment: Wow, thanks! I just tested this out and this is exactly what I was looking for. I scrolled through all the different actions and I must of not noticed this one. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah I hear ya,  there is just so many it is very easy to miss, glad that one worked.